# Why does my desktop "ghost" after removing Python?

Tags: python

I was getting an error message ("ImportError: No module named webkit") and one of my friends suggested to remove Python and then do a `dist-upgrade`. I followed their advice and rebooted but now my desktop shows ghosts of the last thing shown above it.

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Get smarter friends. Check the expertise of the person before following advice. Consider that the advice might not be right. Aim gun at foot; pull trigger.

Comment: Python is an essential part of Ubuntu. Removing Python was a bad idea. Get into recovery mode, and try to reinstall it.